# Multiple WebApp projects within the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I currently have a VERY large webapp project, a DAL layer and a BLL layer and two testing projects in a solution together. I would like to start moving away from ASP.NET webforms and begin moving over to MVC4 with Razor.

I have tried going down the hybrid project route by adding in the correct routes, folders and project guid's into the csproj, but, this seems like a bit of a hack.

Is there a way i can have a Webforms project and a MVC4 project within the same solution, and have them play nicely together when deployed. I.e. if one cannot handle the request given, the other tries to handle it. This way, i am free to migrate the webforms project to MVC over time.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way i can have a Webforms project and a MVC4 project within
>   the same solution, and have them play nicely together when deployed

With ONE ASP.Net and VS 2013, you can make Webforms, MVC and Web API play together pretty nicely. [Check out this reference.](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio)

> if one cannot handle the request given, the other tries to handle it.

There is no IN-THE-BOX solution for dynamic switching between MVC and webforms. You have to use concepts like HttpModules or HttpModules or Routing etc., to get to have customized request handling.